# Integrating custom built portal with Apigee API service gateway

Tags: apigee

I have some questions on Apigee API Management solution especially when a customer want to procure API Gateway but want to build a “customer built” API Developer & Management Portal.

1. How can we expose back end services configured in API Proxy as searchable services using a custom built portal application? We understand, Apigee Developer portal is the way to go, but if the customer wants to use his own portal, how we can make the services discoverable?
2. How can user management policies defined in API Proxy be made available on a custom built portal application if only Proxy/Gateway component is used.
3. The API Portal ships with an integrated content management system (CMS) for easy customization and corporate skinning. Can this be reverse? Can we integrate the API specific information on a custom built portal application?
4. We understand that Functions such as key generation, user management, and access to APIs could be controlled by the gateway, but how the developer portal would leverage those functions if it’s a custom built Developer portal?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have a custom built developer portal to work as the developer portal provided by Apigee.

There are certain set of Api calls that the custom portal should make to the Apigee Platform, for example when a user registers on the developer portal the portal needs to make a call to create the developer in the enterprise, in order for the developer to be able to create applications and get the api keys.

Similarly when a developer logs into the developer portal and creates an application from the developer portal another api call should be made to create the same application for the developer in the enterprise portal and then display the application details such as the Api Product, application keys etc..

All the information related to the developer applications are stored in the Apigee enterprise portal and every time the developer logs into the portal all these  information has to be pulled from the enterprise portal via Api calls and shown to the user.

Please refer to the below link to get a list of all the apis available to communicate with the  Apigee platform.

http://apigee.com/docs/apigee-api-platform-console

Regards,
Sudheesh